# Помогите новичку, некорректный вывод на экран с цикла-выводятся черные вопросы

Tags: php

умнейшие. Программа должна выводить стихотворение сверху вниз построчно.Кодировка выставлена правильная , первая часть программы выводится правильно,но а цикл - с ним беда, во-первых, первый цикл выводит только 1 раз, во-вторых, при выводе я вижу только черные вопросы,хотя кодировку выставил,в чем проблема ? Если вопрос глупый,простите- я тупой

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
</head>
<body>
</body>
<?php


mb_internal_encoding('utf-8');

$text = 
'Дым табачный воздух выел.
Комната —
глава в крученыховском аде.
Вспомни —
за этим окном
впервые
руки твои, исступлённый, гладил.
Сегодня сидишь вот,
сердце в железе.
День ещё —
выгонишь,
может быть, изругав.
В мутной передней долго не влезет
сломанная дрожью рука в рукав.';


$lines = preg_split('/\\r\\n?|\\n/', $text);
var_dump ($lines);

foreach ($lines as $key=>$value){
    $value1=explode(" ",$value);

    foreach ($value1 as $key1=>$value1){
        echo "$value1[$key] <br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: `$value1 as $key1=>$value1` - слева и справа `$value1`, вам не кажется это странным?

Comment: Вы правы,в этом была проблема,спасибо,я предупреждал о нюансах

Answer (score 0):

Если вам надо вывести просто построчно достаточно одного цикла.

```
foreach ($lines as $value) {
     echo "$value <br>";
}
```

Со вторым циклом будет вывод каждого слова на новой строке

```
foreach ($lines as $value){
    $value1=explode(" ",$value);

    foreach ($value1 as $value2){
        echo "$value2 <br>";
    }
}
```